# Magento 2 Ajax request fails

Tags: admin, magento2, ajax, magento2-dev-beta, http-request

I made an ajax request (in the admin html) and got the following response:

"{"error":true,"message":"You entered an invalid Secret Key. Please refresh the page."}"

> new Ajax.Request('getAjaxExportUrl() ?>', {
>               method:     'get',
>               parameters: {
>                   "store" : "someStore"
>               }

.

> public function getAjaxExportUrl() 
>       {
>       return $this->getUrl('someURL');
>       }

What's wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Magento is using secure key validation in admin aria.

Simplest way to use secure key is use POST and add form_key to data. Example:

```
jQuery.ajax( {
    url: 'http://mage.dev/admin/vendor/module/validateTest',
    data: {form_key: window.FORM_KEY},
    type: 'POST'
}).done(function(a) { 
    console.log(a); // log: {a: "b"}
});
```

Comment: Do you know why this fails ? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103068/magento2-ajax-fails-in-admin

Comment: May be your admin URL doesn't have secure key in it. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104069/magento2-how-to-generate-admin-url-with-secure-key-from-a-controller