# Magento2 ajax fails in admin

Tags: magento2, admin, ajax

In admin I have the following controller:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

class Test extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {       
         return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData([
            'this' => 'test'
        ]);
    }
}
```

in Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="module" frontName="module">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

In javascript I do the following ajax request to that controller:

```
jQuery.ajax( {
        url: location.protocol + '//' + location.host+'/admin/module/test',
        data: {form_key: window.FORM_KEY},
        type: 'POST'
    }).done(function(a) { 
        console.log(a); 
    });
```

And I receive 404 error

```
http://mydomain/admin/module/test?isAjax=true 404 (Forbidden)
```

as well.. same thing...

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should make the call to `location.protocol + '//' + location.host+'/admin/vendor/module/test'`

**[EDIT]**
or try 
`location.protocol + '//' + location.host+'/admin/module/test'`

Comment: nope... didnt work, same thing - 404 forbidden

Comment: how does your `etc/adminhtml/routes.xml` file look like?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="module" frontName="module">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>

Comment: see my edit. If that does not work, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: sadly, it didn't ... :( 10x anyway the weirdest error though ... 404 Forbidden... I've never seen this before

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The reason could be, that the formkey is invalid, because it is not added to the url.

My advice:

- Do not use `location.protocol` or something else like `location.host`
- Instead let the url be generated by PHP and then pass it to javascript in phtml file or as a variable (for example in a function created by block).

Creation in PHP (from block) is:

```
$this->getUrl('frontname/myController', $params )
```

where:

- `frontname` is defined in your route-file `etc/adminhtml/routes.xml`,
- `$params` are the post-parameters (can be an empty array).

Also it can be a cache-problems:

- Check if you have caches disabled
- run the command: `php bin/magento cache:clean`
- run the command: `rm -r var/generation`

Comment: Clearing the cache did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

Ок, this does not make any sense to me.

In Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/ I have the fallowing controllers:

```
Controller/Adminhtml/Double.php
Controller/Adminhtml/Module/Index.php
Controller/Adminhtml/Test/Test.php
```

If I send anjax to :

```
location.protocol + '//' + location.host+'/admin/module/module/index
```

or

```
location.protocol + '//' + location.host+'/admin/module/test/test
```

they both succeed. If I send ajax to ajax to

```
location.protocol + '//' + location.host+'/admin/module/double
```

i get

```
http://mydomain/admin/module/double?isAjax=true 404 (Forbidden)
```

Wtf is this :) And what is error 404 Forbidden :) ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it is possible, but i had the same error and i fixed it adding

```
/**
 * Array of actions which can be processed without secret key validation
 *
 * @var string[]
 */
protected $_publicActions = ['test'];
```

and it starts to work, but now it continues to work even if `$_publicActions` is removed or commented out.