# Magento2: How to get adminUrl in js file using something like 'mage/url'?

Tags: magento2, javascript, drop-downs, custom-admin-url, admin-url

I am trying to populate an adminhtml dropdown when another dropdown is selected using AJAX and 'mage/url' returns the frontend url. This is my code:

**app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/form/element/options.js**

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'mage/url',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form'
], function (_, uiRegistry, select, url, form) {
    'use strict';

    return select.extend({

        onUpdate: function (value) {
            var field1 = uiRegistry.get('index = type');
            var urlString = url.build('stannp/template/ajax');

            if (field1.value() == value) {

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: urlString,
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {type: value},
                    complete: function (data) {
                      //
                    },
                    done: function (response) {
                        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.responseText)));
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.responseText)));
                    }
                });
            }
            return this._super();
        },
    });
});
```

**urlString** returns **stannp/template/ajax**

I tried with BASE_URL too and by getting the current url and splitting it, but it doesn't work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so using a couple of other answers on this website:
[Priank's](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/41318/priyank) on this [Get Base Url Or Dynamic Url In view Js or html files](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139071/get-base-url-or-dynamic-url-in-view-js-or-html-files) and [KAndy's](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/12503/kandy) answer on this [Magento 2 Ajax request fails](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88717/magento-2-ajax-request-fails/88719), I managed to find the solution to my problem.

Here is the code:

**app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/frontname_controller_action.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>
            page title
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="form_name"/>
            <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Controller\Action" name="some_name"  />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Namespace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php**

```
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template; 
use Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig\Reader;


class Index extends Template {

    protected $_template = 'Namespace_Module::frontname/controller/config.phtml';

    protected $_configReader;

    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, Reader $reader, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_configReader = $reader;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getAdminBaseUrl(){
        $config = $this->_configReader->load();
        $adminSuffix = $config['backend']['frontName'];
        return $this->getBaseUrl() . $adminSuffix . '/';
    } 
}
```

**app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/frontname/contoller/config.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'mage/url'
    ], function(url) {
        return url.setBaseUrl('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAdminBaseUrl();?>');
    });
</script>
```

***This allowed me to do this in my ajax call:***

```
              //build the string using the base url set in the phtml file
              var urlString = url.build('frontname/controller/action');

              //if one of the values from dropdown 1 has been selected
              if (field1.value() == value) {

                  jQuery.ajax({
                    url: urlString + "?type=" + value,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {form_key: window.FORM_KEY}, //very important!!!
                    showLoader: true,
                    complete: function (data) {
                        //build the array of values for dropdown 2
                        var resultArray = [];
                        resultArray.push({
                            value: '0',
                            label: 'Blank Template',
                        });

                        jQuery.each(data.responseJSON, function(index, el) {

                           resultArray.push({
                               value: index,
                               label: el,
                           });
                        });
                        //change values in dropdown 2
                        templates.setOptions(resultArray);
                    },
                    done: function (response) {
                        return true;
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.responseText)));
                    }
                });
           }
```

Comment: it doesn't contain secret key!