# Magento 2 mage/url in Admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, adminhtml, knockoutjs

I have followed this solution [Magento2: How to get adminUrl in js file using something like 'mage/url'?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205839/magento2-how-to-get-adminurl-in-js-file-using-something-like-mage-url) and its perfectly working. But when i add **Add Secret Key to URLs** that time it don't work.

Is there any way i could add this secret key to the url?